# How to list available test classes

Tags: unit-testing, gradle

Is there a way to get Gradle (1.12) to list all of the available unit test classes in a project?

I'm considering putting a front-end on a series of tests we use in my company, and since new tests are always being added, I need a way to get a list of available tests.

I realize that I could scan the actual project for classes that reside in the test sources tree, but I was hoping for something easily parsed from Gradle.  I just don't know if that's really an option and I'm having trouble getting decent search results since "test" is such a generic word.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no official API in Gradle to expose this information. You can check if [ClassScanner.java](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/testing-jvm/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/testing/detection/DefaultTestClassScanner.java) is what you need. Either look at Gradle sources or it is also used in [EclipseTestExecuter.java](https://github.com/radimk/PDETestExampleProjectsWithGradle/blob/master/buildSrc/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/tooling/pde/EclipseTestExecuter.java) Keep in mind that it is an implementation detail.

A simpler approach is to run these tests and enable logging where you will print names of executed tests. There is an example how to this in Gradle documentation I think.

Comment: OK, if nobody comes up with a solution, I'll swing back and mark this as the accepted answer.  Ping me if I forget for some reason.  Since I'm trying to build a Node.js app as the front end for running the gradle tests, Java code isn't going to help me.  That's why I was hoping to get Gradle to list them.  Otherwise I'll just have to build the list myself.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since gradle 8.3, there is a [test dry run mode](https://%27https://docs.gradle.org/8.3-rc-1/release-notes.html#dry-run-mode-for-test-execution%27) that can be enabled either with the command-line option `--test-dry-run` or via the [`dryRun`](https://docs.gradle.org/8.3-rc-1/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.testing.Test:dryRun) property  for exactly this purpose:

```
./gradlew test --test-dry-run
```